# C166; Stack only allowed in near memory

Tags: assembly, infineon

I am trying to understand this Assembly macro that sets the stack pointer to the location of a Task Stack of a RTOS.
There are a few Assembly commands that I don't know and 
where I can't find that much information of.

This code points the User stack pointer to the stack of a Micrium Task (uC/OS III RTOS).
But these tasks are only allowed to lay into near memory, and that is probably because of these assembly functions.

That's why I'm trying to find out what exactly is happening here. And why the stack can only be in near memory.
After that I would like to find out if I can rewrite this to support tasks stacks outside of the near memory.

This assembly code is running on a XE169 chip (C166 Family):

```
LOAD_USRSTK_PTR .MACRO
    EXTP    #PAG _OSTCBHighRdyPtr,#02h    ; R4/R5 = OSTCBHighRdyPtr
    MOV     R4,POF _OSTCBHighRdyPtr
    MOV     R5,POF (_OSTCBHighRdyPtr+2)

    EXTP    R5,#01h                       ; user stack ptr = OSTCBHighRdyPtr->OSTCBStkPtr
    MOV     R15,[R4]
.ENDM
```

**This is how far I've found out what each line of code does:**

```
LOAD_USRSTK_PTR .MACRO
```

Start of macro with the name LOAD_USRSTK_PTR

```
EXTP    #PAG _OSTCBHighRdyPtr,#02h
```

Begin Extended Page Sequence, the next 2 instructions are part of the Extended Page Sequence

What does the #PAG _OSTCBHighRdyPtr part in this instruction mean, does this get the Page part of of the address where OSTCBHighRdyPtr is pointing to.

So the bits 23-14 of the pointer. When looking at the below image:
[image]

```
MOV     R4,POF _OSTCBHighRdyPtr
```

Write _OSTCBHighRdyPtr into Register 4. What does POF mean in this instruction, does it get the value of the pointer and store that in Register 4?

```
MOV     R5,POF (_OSTCBHighRdyPtr+2)
```

Write the value of at 2 addresses further as the address of OSTCBHighRdyPtr to Register 5. 
What does POF mean in this instruction
Is it in this case copying the ExtPtr address? because this address is 4 bytes long, and the Register only 2 bytes?

```
EXTP    R5,#01h                       ; user stack ptr = OSTCBHighRdyPtr->OSTCBStkPtr
```

Begin Extended Page Sequence. Next 1 instruction is part of the Extended Page Sequence. 
R5 = Register 5 what exactly is done with this register

```
MOV     R15,[R4]
```

Move the value of Register 4 into Register 15, R15 is the User Stack Pointer

```
.ENDM
```

End of Macro

The _OSTCBHighRdyPtr is a pointer to a struct, the (beginning) of this struct looks like this:

```
struct os_tcb {
    CPU_STK      *StkPtr;         /* Pointer to current top of stack                  */
    void         *ExtPtr;         /* Pointer to user definable data for TCB extension */
    CPU_CHAR     *NamePtr;        /* Pointer to task name                             */
    CPU_STK      *StkLimitPtr;    /* Pointer used to set stack 'watermark' limit      */
    ....
}
```

CPU_STK is a typedef of  unsigned  short __near.

The sizes of the items in this struct are:

```
StkPtr = 2 bytes (in near memory thus 2 bytes is enough)
ExtPtr = 4 bytes
NamePtr = 4 bytes
StkLimitPtr = 2 bytes (in near memory thus 2 bytes is enough)
```